# How to define libusb_log_cb function in the class?

Tags: c++, libusb

How can I define the libusb_log_cb function inside the class?  I need access to variables of this class.

Exxample:

foo.h

```
class foo
{
    ...
private:
    int r;
    void handleLog(libusb_context *ctx, enum libusb_log_level level, const char* str);
};
```

foo.cpp

```
...

void foo::handleLog(libusb_context *ctx, enum libusb_log_level level, const char* str)
{
    ...
    std::cout << r << "\n";
}

...

libusb_set_log_cb(..., handleLog, ...); // Error. Cause this function is a member of the foo class
```

Comment: You cannot. Libusb authors have made it impossible so you may want to complain to them.

Comment: There is about a zillion duplicate questions on this site alone, you can search for them with "how to pass member function as callback \[c++]". Basically, a C callback needs an additional `void*` argument to pass user data in. This API doesn't have one, so people who wrote it either have no idea what they are doing, or have a very good reason (which they prefer to keep secret) to deviate from the universally accepted solution.